# Hierarchy Without CTE - Get Direct Children

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table for assets:

`id|name|parentId`

The view I'm trying to build is for an asset is:

```
{
 'Id': ......,
 'Name': ....,
 'ChildrenIds': []
}
```

I need a query that selects TOP 50 assets and its direct children (so results could be more than 50 results).

I have a CTE that works, but its slow (5 seconds, parentId & id is indexed):

```
WITH MyCte as
(
    SELECT TOP 50 a.Id, a.Name, a.ParentAssetId
    FROM assets a
    UNION ALL
    SELECT a2.AssetId, a2.ParentAssetId
    FROM assets a2
    INNER JOIN MyCte cte ON cte.Id = a2.ParentAssetId
)
SELECT * From MyCte;
```

This join query does half of what I want.

```
SELECT TOP 50 a.Id, a.Name, a.ParentAssetId
FROM assets a
LEFT JOIN assets a2 ON a2.ParentAssetId = a.Id
```

Problem with JOIN, it gives me 50 results, and that's it. I need the descendant info to build a view. I could do 2 queries, but I'd rather not do that.

Any suggestions?

Maybe there is a better way for me to build this view? Without the 50 + N requirement? **You can use a GROUP BY with STRING_AGG, but I worry about the size limitation.**

```
SAMPLE DATA:

1,Site1,NULL
2,Site2,1
3,Site3,1
4,Site4,2
5,Site5,NULL
```

TOP 3 ORDER BY id DESC results will return

```
1,Site1,NULL
2,Site2,1
3,Site3,1
4,Site4,2
```

BUT I guess ideally something like this:

```
1,Site1,NULL|2,Site2,1|3,Site3,1
2,Site2,1|4,Site4,2
3,Site3,1
```

Comment: TOP without ORDER BY?!?

Comment: That CTE won't work either; the top statement has more columns than the bottom (`ID`, `Name` and `ParentAssetId` vs `AssetID` and `ParentAssetId`). But the only way to read hierarchical data is using a rCTE (though you could use a `WHILE` or `CURSOR` but I highly recommend against that), or creating static data (which would be initialised with a recursive solution, like an rCTE).

Comment: If you only need one layer of children (not the children's children/grandchildren) then can you use your `JOIN` version and instead of initially selecting on `assets` in your `FROM` select on the top 50 assets: `SELECT a.id, a.name, a2.id, a2.name FROM (SELECT top 50 * FROM assets) a LEFT JOIN assets a2 ON a2.ParentAssetID = a.Id;`?

Comment: Also, perhaps the reason the query is slow is due to a lack of or poor choice of indexing?

Comment: Please provide a sample data and expected results. I believe there is better ways if you provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: @Sami added sample data and results.

Comment: What are your "top 50 assets"?  Should that be "Nodes without a parent" (root of hierarchy)?  What happens if there are _more_ than 50 of these?

Comment: _"TOP 3 ORDER BY id DESC results will return"_ That's wrong because you say `ORDER BY ID DESC` so it should returs IDs 5, 4 and 3

Answer (score 0):

You can use a temp table to achieve what you need.

```
SELECT TOP (50) a.Id, a.Name, a.ParentAssetId
INTO #Assets
FROM assets a;

INSERT INTO #Assets
SELECT a2.Id, a2.Name, a2.ParentAssetId
FROM #Assets a
JOIN assets a2 ON a2.ParentAssetId = a.Id;

SELECT *
FROM #Assets;
```

Note that this is not deterministic because there's no ORDER BY when using TOP.

Comment: This works, I'm trying to figure out if I can make this a view or not.

Comment: You can't make this a view.   You can make a stored proc or function.   That said, I'd be surprised if it's any faster than the CTE in your question that you say is slow.

Comment: **WARNING** : Without an `ORDER BY`, the `TOP` used in the CTE will return a non-deterministic set of rows - including leaf children, who only have parents.

Answer (score 0):

You could use this CTE and make a view from it:

```
WITH MyCte as
(
    SELECT TOP 50 a.Id, a.Name, a.ParentAssetId
    FROM assets a
)
SELECT cte.*, a1.Id as ChildId, a1.Name as ChildName
FROM MyCte cte
INNER JOIN assets a1
 ON a1.ParentAssetId=cte.Id
```

Admittedly this will give you a different kind of result set than the UNION CTE in your question, but I'm assuming that you can make a simple adjustment to your consumer application to handle it.  It might even be easier/more performant for the app this way, since the relationships are present in the row, and don't have to be extrapolated.

That said, if you are working with a recent-enough Version of SQL Server, you might look into the built-in JSON functions, since it looks like that is the output you are ultimately trying to generate.

Comment: I like this, thank you! I have two questions: 1. is a CTE even needed here? It's essentially a temp table, no?  2. It doesn't seem you can parametrize views. So if I make this a view, I can't prepend TOP to it and I can't pass it in. Do you see a way around it?

Comment: **WARNING** : Without an `ORDER BY`, the `TOP` used in the CTE will return a non-deterministic set of rows - including leaf children, who only have parents.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse yes, true, and that has also been pointed out in a comment on the original question.   I did it here to duplicate (to the extent possible) the functionality of the code in the question.

Comment: @jn1kk, no there's no way to parameterize a VIEW so there's no way to make a view with this query configurable as to how many parents it would return.  Your only options to do that, as I see it, are to use String Aggregation, as you mention in your question, or to make a table-valued function instead of a view.   Or again, look into the JSON functions.  I'm not familiar enough with them to say if they hold an answer.

Answer (score 0):

According to what you provide, and **if** I understand, I think you're looking for

```
WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT TOP 3 *
  FROM T
  ORDER BY ID DESC
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE
UNION
SELECT *
FROM T
WHERE ID IN (SELECT ParentId FROM CTE);
```

**Returns:**

```
+----+-------+----------+
| ID | Name  | ParentId |
+----+-------+----------+
|  1 | Site1 |          |
|  2 | Site2 |        1 |
|  3 | Site3 |        1 |
|  4 | Site4 |        2 |
|  5 | Site5 |          |
+----+-------+----------+
```

Here is a **[`db<>fiddle`](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=5862ca01a5c81e7258753df99fe30d47)**

---

UPDATE:

Since you're looking for a way to pass an `INT` value present the rows number used in `TOP`, you can create an inline table-valued function as

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.MyFunction (@Rows INT = 1)
RETURNS TABLE  
AS  
RETURN   
( 
  WITH CTE AS
  (
    SELECT TOP (@Rows) *
    FROM T
    ORDER BY ID DESC
  )
    SELECT *
    FROM CTE
    UNION
    SELECT *
    FROM T
    WHERE ID IN (SELECT ParentId FROM CTE)
);
```

and just call it as

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.MyFunction(2)
```

**[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d34884cc0f08cd060f994347ee7eebaf)**

Comment: This also looks good, it seems you can also make it a join. My last hangup is if you see a way for me to pass in the TOP X number. If I make this a view, this will pre-default to 3. I'm trying to see if I can make it configurable. Usually, with a view i do `SELECT TOP 3 dbo.view`.